# Error on inserting geo_point in elasticsearch through java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, geocoding, elastic-stack

I have an index in Elasticsearch in which there is a field of geo_point.
The mapping file is somewhat like this.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test_geo5' -d'
{
"mappings":{
"test_geo5":{  
"properties":{ 
"lat":{ "type": "string","index": "not_analyzed"},
"lon":{ "type": "string","index": "not_analyzed"},
"message_geocoordinates":{ "type": "geo_point"} 
}
}
}
}'
```

I want to insert message_geocoordinates using java code.

So I wrote java code like this

```
String latitude= xxxxx;
String longitude= yyyy;
String message_geocordinates= latitude+","+longitude;
JSONObject jj = new JSONObject();
jj.put("lat", latitude);
jj.put("lon", longitude);
jj.put("message_geocordinates", message_geocordinates);
IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("test_geo5", "iiiii").setSource(jj.toString()).execute().actionGet();
```

and I tried to insert it in Elasticsearch. But I received following exception.

```
MapperParsingExceptionfailed to parse; nested: IllegalStateException[Mixing up field types: class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.StringFieldMapper$StringFieldType != class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.geo.BaseGeoPointFieldMapper$GeoPointFieldType on field message_geocoordinates];
```

So it says that my message_geocoordinates field is String in java but it is GeoPointFieldType for elatic search.

How can I insert geopoint field into elasticsearch using java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by me.

Basically the JSONObject jj that I created must use gson library,but I was using JSON simple library.

Comment: While ingesting data ,when we have to ingest JSON Object into elasticearch Index,the json object must use library com.google.gson.JsonObject instead of org.json.JSONObject.If we use org.json.JSONObject it will give MapperParsingExceptionfailed to parse; nested: IllegalStateException[Mixing up field types: class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.StringFieldMapper$StringFieldType != class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.geo.BaseGeoPointFieldMapper$GeoPointFieldType on field message_geocoordinates] for the field that is mapped as geo_point in elasticsearch mapping

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a data structure which looks like:

```
{
  "message_geocoordinates": {
    "lat": 0.00,
    "lon": 0.00
  }
}
```

Just print your `jj.toString()` and you will see that you are not generating that here.

Note also that I'd use `double` instead of `String` for lat/lon fields.

Update:

Based on your comments, I tried this

```
DELETE test_geo5
PUT test_geo5
{
  "mappings": {
    "test_geo5": {
      "properties": {
        "lat": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "lon": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "message_geocoordinates": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
PUT test_geo5/test_geo5/1
{
  "lon": 28.59,
  "message_geocoordinates": "41.589,28.59",
  "lat": 41.589
}
```

This is working correctly.

Can you check what gives `GET test_geo5/_mapping`?

Comment: I was following this link
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html

It says that my message_geocoordinates fields can be string as well.

I will try your suggestion though.

Comment: And? What jj.toString() prints?

Comment: I made changes suggested by you 
    double latitude=41.589;
    double longitude =28.59;
    String message_geocoordinates=null;

JSONObject jj = new JSONObject();
  message_geocoordinates= latitude+","+longitude;
  jj.put("lat", latitude);
  jj.put("lon", longitude);
  jj.put("message_geocoordinates", message_geocoordinates);
   System.out.println(jj.toString());


and it prints me the output as {"lon":28.59,"message_geocoordinates":"41.589,28.59","lat":41.589}

Comment: So its working when i am ingesting data from elasticsearch using PUT
But I am facing this error when I am pushing it using java code which is mentioned above in my question

Comment: I don't understand how your code can generate "message_geocordinates" as you don't use it when you create your jj object. Or I have a trouble with my eyes may be...

Comment: Ohh Sorry.Updated my java code.
So basically i added message_geocordinates to my josnobject and pushing it into elasticsearch.
The latitude and longitude fields are string.
As per your suggestion I changed them to double but that also does not help.

Comment: I don't understand. May be you can try to recreate a full code sample which can be reproduced and push it to a github repo? Your java code seems to send the same data as the one I'm able to send to the REST interface. So I'm curious to reproduce it.